# use OnClientClick on bootstrap modal to avoid postback

Tags: vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, postback, onclientclick

Am using vb.net in asp.net to create my project. I use also a bootstrap modal to get data from client.

In the modal I have buttons and textboxes that get the data from user. there is a FINISH button that ends the process and closes the modal

the problem is that the other buttons are not supposed to close the modal, but make some calculations and processes. At one hand I need the postback in order to tiger the events of the buttons, And at the other hand the post back closes the modal, and i have to re-open it at the end of each process. This action makes the modal close and re-open after each click, and it is not Nice or Convenient

I thought that if I disable the postback of the buttons, and use the OnClientClick to catch the client click, this will work for me.  **But the Question is how can I make the OnClientClick Call a server side code (Sub)?**

Any other Suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnClientClick is just that the CLIENT CLICK it doesn't translate into a server side method.  Each ASP.Net server control has an OnClick event which is associated with a server based method, but that would give you the exact same scenario that you're dealing with now.

In this situation, I would have the secondary buttons (i.e. the ones that don't close the modal by behavior) use AJAX to send/receive data from the server (accessing an ASHX file or some other handler/WebAPI). This removes the entire postback situation entirely which sidesteps the issue.